# OpenXml header settings not set in Word

Tags: ms-word, openxml, office-js

I want to load a Word document from a Base64 string with Word Web Addin. The document I want to load has a primary header and a header for the first page. After the document is loaded the primary header appears on the first page instead of the header for the first page. How can I set [this setting](https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/100d66c1-77ae-4521-b156-4032ae0372d0.png) with the [Word JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word?view=office-js)?

This is my code. The Base64 string is both times the same. The header for the first page is shown on the first page
if I [create a new document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.application?view=office-js#createdocument-base64file-) from the same Base64 encoded string.

```
<!-- insert Ooxml -->
Word.run(function (context) {
    var doc = context.application.createDocument(data.base64);

    var primaryHeaderXml = doc.sections.getFirst().getHeader("primary").getOoxml();
    var firstHeaderXml = doc.sections.getFirst().getHeader("firstPage").getOoxml();
    var evenHeaderXml = doc.sections.getFirst().getHeader("evenPages").getOoxml();

    return context.sync().then(function() {
        Word.run(function(ctx) {
            if (primaryHeaderXml.value !== null) {
                ctx.document.sections.getFirst().getHeader("primary").insertOoxml(primaryHeaderXml.value, "replace");
            }
            if (firstHeaderXml.value !== null) {
                ctx.document.sections.getFirst().getHeader("firstPage").insertOoxml(firstHeaderXml.value, "replace");
            }
            if (evenHeaderXml.value !== null) {
                ctx.document.sections.getFirst().getHeader("evenPages").insertOoxml(evenHeaderXml.value, "replace");
            }
        });
    });
}).catch(function (error) {
    handleError(error);
});


<!-- create new Document -->
Word.run(function(context) {
    var doc = context.application.createDocument(data.base64);
    doc.open();

    return context.sync();
});
```

Comment: Your problem description isn't clear. You don't provide the code that "loads a Word document" with the two different headers. Then when you say creating a new document from the Base64-encoded document: do you mean the original document or the one that's been changed in the first part of the code? Are you saying if you then run the first part of the code on the new document it works? Or that loading the document that was changed using the first part of the code then shows the correct headers?

Comment: As I understand it, now, your question is "How to activate the Different First Page setting in an existing, opened Word document using the Office JS APIs?" The functionality is not (currently) available in the APIs, nor is it simple to solve using Open XML as it involves more than simply inserting open xml content into the body. In order to activate this option References need to be generated in the document for "default", "even" and "first page" headers and footers.

Comment: This means the entire Open XML OPC flat-file content needs to be manipulated at a level not allowed by the Word application on a file opened in the UI. In my experience, Word ignores changes at this level when such Word Open XML is passed to an opened document. Programmatically, it can only be done on the closed document or through the COM object model.